# How do I use For loop to get output

Tags: xml, vb.net-2010

In my function I would like to use a For loop to get all the statutes inside the object **objXmlBcaResponseDoc** xml. In my case there are 2 statutes. I would like the output to look like the one I have posted here below. 
I am not sure how to do the For loop. The commented For loop is from another function but it is not working inside this function.

**I would like to get the following output which shows a count of 2 and the 2 statuteIds**

```
<BasicSearchQueryResponse xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/service/4.0">
<StatutesXml>
    <Statutes runType="Request" runDateTime="2015-03-17T10:23:04" totalCount="2">
        <ns1:Statute xmlns:ns1="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/messages/4.0">
            <StatuteId xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">8471</StatuteId>
            <Chapter xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">60</Chapter>
            <Section xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">55</Section>
            <Subdivision xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0"/>
        </ns1:Statute>
        <ns1:Statute>
            <StatuteId xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">9722</StatuteId>
            <Chapter xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">90</Chapter>
            <Section xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">25</Section>
            <Subdivision xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0"/>
        </ns1:Statute>
    </Statutes>
</StatutesXml>
```

My xml doc is found inside **objXmlBcaResponseDoc**
Here is xml inside objXmlBcaResponseDoc object

```
<BasicSearchQueryResponse xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/service/4.0">
<ns1:Statutes xmlns:ns1="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/messages/4.0">
    <ns1:Statute>
        <StatuteId xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">8471</StatuteId>
        <Chapter xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">60</Chapter>
        <Section xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">55</Section>
        <Subdivision xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0"/>
    </ns1:Statute>
    <ns1:Statute>
        <StatuteId xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">9722</StatuteId>
        <Chapter xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">90</Chapter>
        <Section xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0">25</Section>
        <Subdivision xsi:nil="true" xmlns="http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/4.0"/>
    </ns1:Statute>
```

**My Function**

```
 Function GetStatutesByChapter(ByVal aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode As XmlNode, ByVal aobjXMLNameSpaceManager As XmlNamespaceManager, ByVal aobjBroker As ServiceCatalog.Library.v4.Broker) As XmlDocument
        Dim objXmlRequestMessageDoc As XmlDocument
        Dim objXmlResponseMessageDoc As XmlDocument
        Dim intCount As Integer
        aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("Chapter found.", 1)

        objXmlResponseMessageDoc = New XmlDocument
        'Add the first element into the document GetStatuteByChapter with its namespace
        objXmlResponseMessageDoc.AppendChild(objXmlResponseMessageDoc.CreateElement("BasicSearchQueryResponse", "http://crimnet.state.mn.us/mnjustice/statute/service/4.0"))

        'Build the initial response document
        objXmlResponseMessageDoc = New XmlDocument
        'Add the first element into the document GetStatutesResponse with its namespace
        objXmlResponseMessageDoc.AppendChild(objXmlResponseMessageDoc.CreateElement("GetStatutesResponse", "http://www.courts.state.mn.us/StatuteService/1.0"))
        'Add a child node to the GetStatutesResponse node
        objXmlResponseMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ss:GetStatutesResponse", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlResponseMessageDoc.CreateElement("StatutesXml", "http://www.courts.state.mn.us/StatuteService/1.0"))
        objXmlResponseMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ss:GetStatutesResponse/ss:StatutesXml", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlResponseMessageDoc.CreateElement("Statutes", "http://www.courts.state.mn.us/StatuteService/1.0"))
        'Convert the node Statutes into an element and set the runType attribute (runType="Request") by adding it's value Request 
        CType(objXmlResponseMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ss:GetStatutesResponse/ss:StatutesXml/ss:Statutes", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager), System.Xml.XmlElement).SetAttribute("runType", "Request")
        'Convert the node Statutes into an element and set the attribute (runDateTime="2015-03-05T10:29:40") by adding it 
        CType(objXmlResponseMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ss:GetStatutesResponse/ss:StatutesXml/ss:Statutes", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager), System.Xml.XmlElement).SetAttribute("runDateTime", Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"))

        'Create the BCA request message
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc = New XmlDocument
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("ns")))
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("ns1")))
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest/ns1:BasicSearchCriteria", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns2:Chapter", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("st")))

        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest/ns1:BasicSearchCriteria", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns2:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("st")))
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest/ns1:BasicSearchCriteria", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns2:Subdivision", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("st")))

        'Uncomment last working section below
        objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria/st:Chapter", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Chapter", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText

        'check if there is a section and or subdivision if it is there then set the value
        If Not (aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager) Is Nothing) Then
            objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria/st:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        End If
        If Not (aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Subdivision", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager) Is Nothing) Then
            objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria/st:Subdivision", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Subdivision", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
        End If
        'check if there is a section and or subdivision if it is there then set the value
        aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseSnapshot(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.OuterXml, "Request Message", 1)

        'Call the BCA service
        intCount = 0
        'This is where I want to use a For loop to check for the statutes found using the Chapter

        'Loop through each Id
        'For Each objXmlStatuteIdNode In aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectNodes("ss:Statute/ss:StatuteId/ss:Id[string-length(.)>0]", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager)
            'Create the BCA request message
            'objXmlRequestMessageDoc = New XmlDocument
            'objXmlRequestMessageDoc.AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns:SingleStatuteRequest", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("ns")))

            'objXmlRequestMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:SingleStatuteRequest", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns:statuteId", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("ns")))

            'objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns:statuteId", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = objXmlStatuteIdNode.InnerText aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseSnapshot(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.OuterXml, "Request Message", 1)

            'intCount = intCount + 1
            'objXmlBcaResponseDoc = New XmlDocument
            'File name is BCASearchQueryResponse.xml
            'objXmlBcaResponseDoc.Load("\\j00000swebint\mscapps\deve\appfiles\temp\BCASearchQueryResponse.xml")
            'objXmlResponseMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ss:StatutesXml/ss:Statutes", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlResponseMessageDoc.ImportNode(objXmlBcaResponseDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:Statute", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager), True))
        'Next
        'Count how many Statute nodes found
        CType(objXmlResponseMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ss:BasicSearchQueryResponse/ss:StatutesXml/ss:Statutes", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager), System.Xml.XmlElement).SetAttribute("totalCount", CStr(intCount))

        Return objXmlResponseMessageDoc
    End Function
```

Comment: What are you hoping to extract specifically? Could you add a sample output?

Comment: I would like to get the output as I have shown in the first xml under the line **I would like to get the following output which shows a count of 2 and the 2 statuteIds** . This shows a count of 2 and the 2 StatuteId

Answer (score 0):

I used the following if statement to solve my issue. And then used a count to add the statuteIds

```
 If Not aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager) Is Nothing Then
                objXmlRequestMessageDoc.SelectSingleNode("ns:BasicSearchQueryRequest/ns1:BasicSearchCriteria", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).AppendChild(objXmlRequestMessageDoc.CreateElement("ns2:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager.LookupNamespace("st")))
                objXmlRequestMessageDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("ns1:BasicSearchCriteria/st:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText = aobjXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Section", aobjXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText
            End If
```